# How to find database name in rails console

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

This is odd. In my Rails 4 database.yml I have the following:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: inspector_development
  password: 
  pool: 5
```

I copied the production database from Heroku and imported it using this form into my local copy of Postgresql

```
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url --account personal`
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U sam -d inspector_development latest.dump
```

THe result showed the 88 expected users in PGadmin in the inspector_development database on osx. However, even after restarting the rails app, the User table still shows only one user, not the 88 I see in PGadmin.

I've googled for how to determine what Rails sees as the properties of the database name in order to determine where is it finding these non-existent records?

Looking more closely at the User table in PGadmin I see zero columns. Perhaps PGadmin is mistaken? I'm unable to determine where the db Rails is looking for so that I can troubleshoot this, thx, sam

Comment: Try `rails db` from your application root see to which database it connects. It should open postgres console with `inspector_development=#` if this is your database for development

Comment: I usually restore it to a different database name and point database.yml to that one. Haven't had issues with this approach so far.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This works in Rails 3 and Rails 4

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

But this only works with drivers that have implemented that method. For example, it will not work for SQLite but will work with mysql and postgres.

Answer (score 4):

For Postgres what also works is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.config` which will give you more detailed output about all your database configuration:

```rb
=> {:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"unicode", :port=>5432, :host=>"appdb", :pool=>5, :username=>"postgres", :password=>"example", :database=>"app_dev"}
```

**This works in Rails 5.2.6***

**EDIT:**
Thanks @masukomi for the comment. Looks like they removed the `.config` method. As I'm using **Rails 7.0.3** now then I checked how does it work there. Turns out the same:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database
```

Comment: This didn't work for me in rails 6, (possibly just some funkyness with our setup) but `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` did at least provide the database name.